# Draw Ascii character above rectangle with pygame

Tags: python, drawing, pygame, game-engine, roguelike

I'm trying to make a rogue like using pygame.

[image]

Actually i have no problem to draw the first grid which represent the background of game (using `mapLoaded` which contain the original map and `drawMap()` function which return a list of `Case` Object).

I love rectangle but for future i want to draw on top of this rectangle the ascii Character stored into `Case` object.

Using this method for overriding rect by char, i can create later `Object` like player "@" which is also draw on top of this background rectangle or character.

[image: above rectangle]

My question is related in this image, how can i draw (and later move) an ascii character (here the player `@`) on top center of the `pygame.draw.rect()` function used to draw each cell of the background (using character attribute defined in `Case`).

My init code :

```
import os
import drawRogue as draw

mapLoaded = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

class Object:
    def __init__(self,x,y,char,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.color = color

        def move(self,dx,dy):
            if not map[self.x + dx][self.y + dy].blocked:
                self.x = self.x + dx
                self.y = self.y + dy

class Case:
    #a tile of the map and its properties
    def __init__(self, char, blocked):
        self.blocked = blocked
        self.char =  char


#Afficher seulement une partie du monde... tres vaste comme vous le voyez...        
def drawMap(mymap):
    tileMap = []
    for line in mymap:
        tileLine = []
        for value in line:
            if value == 1:
                tileLine.append(Case("#",False))
            else:
                tileLine.append(Case(".",True))
        tileMap.append(tileLine)
    return tileMap

clear = lambda: os.system('clear')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    clear()
    tileMap = drawMap(mapLoaded)
    draw.drawInit()
    draw.addColorRules("#",(255,255,255))
    draw.addColorRules(".",(0,0,0))
    draw.drawScreen(tileMap,40)
    while True:
        draw.drawScreen(tileMap, 40)
        draw.events()
```

My actual code for drawing background into `drawRogue.py` :

```
import sys, pygame

colorRules = {}

def drawInit():
    pygame.init()

def drawScreen(t_view,speed):

    grid_size = grid_rows, grid_cols = len(t_view), len(t_view)
    square_pixels = 15
    base_offset = 30
    size = width, height = (2*base_offset)+(grid_cols*square_pixels), (2*base_offset)+(grid_rows*square_pixels)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    render_steps = True
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    for row in xrange(grid_rows):
        for col in xrange(grid_cols):
            for char in colorRules.keys():
                if (t_view[row][col].char == char):
                    FillSquare(screen, base_offset, square_pixels,(row, col), colorRules[char])

    #draw the outer border
    border_rect = (base_offset, base_offset, (grid_cols*square_pixels), (grid_rows*square_pixels))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (150,150,0), border_rect, 2)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(speed)

def FillSquare(screen, base_offset, square_pixels, loc, color):
    row = loc[0]
    col = loc[1]
    off_x = base_offset + col * square_pixels
    off_y = base_offset + row * square_pixels
    rect = (off_x+4, off_y+4,  square_pixels - 6, square_pixels - 6)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

def addColorRules(char, color):
    colorRules[char] = color

def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

You can dowload and test the two python files here :

[File1](http://file.carthageo.fr/f/97823109ac/)

[File2](http://file.carthageo.fr/f/0cd9af641f/)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about what your specific question is?

Comment: I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: I very much recommend using images instead of text: text depends on installed fonts and sizes and as such is unreliable. Make a few images of all the wanted characters and use those.

Comment: I read pygame create image from font, it's not possible to generate ascii image of the size of my case instead of creating all ascii character manually in png or other ?

Comment: It is, but I don't think it's the best way. Look at [pygame.font.Font](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) if you're intent on doing it that way.

Comment: You can calculate the font size needed, by using [Font.size](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.size) . Once you render the text, it's a regular Surface and Rect that you can draw like normal.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i open a bounty for motivated because i think this is a good question for beginer in pygame Api.

Comment: @Veedrac Rogue-likes are traditionally made using ASCII characters. Its part of the appeal.

Comment: I correct the lacking code, and add python files for curious and helpers :)

Comment: Unrelated, consider using libtcod for a complete RL development library

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I agree, I just think you should have images *of* the ASCII characters because font rendering is a hassle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was mentioned already, [`pygame.font.Font`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) contains methods to draw ASCII characters.  Here is an example of [`render`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) being used to draw a character in a maze.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
resolution = (160, 160)
cell_margin = 14
cell_colors = (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0)
player_character = "@"
player_color = (255, 0, 0)
player_size = 20
current_position = [0, 1]

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
    screen.fill(cell_colors[1])
    player = pygame.font.Font(None, player_size).render(player_character,
                                                        False, player_color)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                key = event.key
                if key == K_UP:
                    move(0, -1)
                elif key == K_RIGHT:
                    move(1, 0)
                elif key == K_DOWN:
                    move(0, 1)
                elif key == K_LEFT:
                    move(-1, 0)
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                return
        draw_maze(screen)
        draw_player(player, screen)
        pygame.display.update()

def draw_maze(screen):
    for row in xrange(len(grid)):
        for column in xrange(len(grid[0])):
            screen.fill(cell_colors[grid[column][row]],
                        get_cell_rect((row, column), screen))

def get_cell_rect(coordinates, screen):
    row, column = coordinates
    cell_width = screen.get_width() / len(grid)
    adjusted_width = cell_width - cell_margin
    return pygame.Rect(row * cell_width + cell_margin / 2,
                       column * cell_width + cell_margin / 2,
                       adjusted_width, adjusted_width)

def draw_player(player, screen):
    rect = player.get_rect()
    rect.center = get_cell_rect(current_position, screen).center
    screen.blit(player, rect)

def move(dx, dy):
    x, y = current_position
    nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
    if nx >= 0 and nx < len(grid) and ny >= 0 and ny < len(grid[0]) and \
       grid[ny][nx]:
        current_position[0] = nx
        current_position[1] = ny

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

I tried to limit the example to the bare essentials of what you're interested in learning.  Basically, what's happening is the entire grid and the character are being redrawn every frame.  The character's position is being modified by the direction keys.  The cells and the character are being drawn according to the rects being returned by `get_cell_rect`.  The character is an ordinary [`Surface`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) created by `pygame.font.Font` at the initialization of the program.

The global variables can be redefined to change the layout, color, sizes, etc.  There is also a [downloadable version](https://gist.github.com/ohsqueezy/6780206) of the example.

Comment: Thanks for this great and detailled answer :) Just another question, do you think is it possible to use `fit` function to resize the `Rect` returned by font.get_rect() function ?

Comment: The [`surface.get_rect`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method gets a rect of the character.  That rect is ordinary and can be resized by `rect.fit`.  There is no `font.get_rect`.  The font module mostly contains methods to tell pygame how to render a surface.  Once font renders the surface, it is identical any other (e.g. one you would get from loading an image).

Comment: So if i understand, to avoid problem caused by font/player size definition, it's possible to force resizing of the surface which contain the font rect to obtain a given and fixed width/height defined for cell size.

Comment: Sure, but it's probably unnecessary.  There are two better alternatives.  The first is to create an intermediate fixed size surface that you blit the font rendering onto.  The second is to resize the font rendering surface's rect without resizing the surface itself.  Actually, why do you need to resize it at all?  In a grid based game, the cell coordinates are all you should need.

Comment: Hum because font render size doesn't fit correctly the cell size (font surface return something like 7*9, and cell is rectangular like 9*9), so i need to refit; i make a gist here with example : https://gist.github.com/reyman/6839004